# Calculating total number of adjacent integers

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to calculate the number of integers excluding repeats line by line from the file.

The output I desire is:

```
Duplicates : 9
Duplicates : 4
Duplicates : 5
Duplicates : 5
Duplicates : 1
Duplicates : 1
Duplicates : 8
```

For further explanation of the concept:
Take the second line of the file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 5
```

At this line there is a 1 so increment the counter because 1 was found first.
Next comes a 2, 2 is not 1 so increment the counter. Next comes a 3, 3 is not a 2 so increment the counter. Next comes a 4, 4 is not a 3 so increment the counter. Next comes a 5, 5 is not a 4 so increment the counter. Next comes a 6, 6 is not a 5 so increment the counter. Next comes a 5, 5 is not a 6 so increment the counter. Next comes a 4, 4 is not a 5 so increment the counter. Next comes a 5, 5 is not a 4 so increment the counter. The number of integers excluding repeats is 9.

Another example:
Take a look a line 8 of the file:

```
34 34 34 34 34
```

At this line there is a 34 so increment the counter. Next comes a 34, 34 is 34 so do not increment the counter. Next comes 34, 34 is 34 so do not increment the counter. Next comes a 34, 34 is 34 so do not increment the counter. Next comes a 34, 34 is 34 so do not increment the counter. The number of integers excluding repeats is 1.

EDIT:
I took the suggestion of a user on here and looked at a few link related to adjacent strings and integers. The output is almost completely correct now when compared to the desired output that I listed above. I will only put the pertain code below:

Output:

```
check1:1
check1:1
check1:2
Duplicates : 6   (Wrong value)
check1:2
Duplicates : 5   (Wrong value)
Duplicates : 5
Duplicates : 5
check1:0
check1:0
check1:0
check1:0
Duplicates : 1
Duplicates : 1
check1:0
check1:0
check1:2
check1:3
check1:3
check1:3
check1:4
check1:5
check1:5
check1:5
check1:5
check1:6
check1:6
Duplicates : 7  (Wrong value)
```

From the output it appears that whenever a test case goes through the if statement `if(array[check] == ch)`, the output is incorrect.

I have been staring at the loops in this function for a long and I am still stumped. 
Any suggestions as to why that loop is leading to incorrect values? Thank you.

Comment: what is the purpose of check-- in the while loop?

Comment: @Pooya While array has an index value, continue checking for adjacent numbers.

Comment: if the first element equals the second element then on the second iteration the check value would be -1 then you are accessing array[-1] in your if statement.

Comment: Can you please tidy up your question so that it is clearer? What is the input that gives the output you have shown? You have dumped a whole lot of test cases and its not clear which (if any) of the test cases forms the input for the shown output. And what is the "desired output" supposed to represent? Your code has no "number" text being printed at all.

Comment: Why not just count transitions from 1 value to the next? A single while loop (rather than 2) should be enough.

Comment: I don't understand why you're decrementing the value of check at all. I see what you're doing, essentially you are removing the adjacent values after reading through them by shifting all other values in the array to the left. You seem to also be using 0 terminated arrays but this isn't shown in your example inputs or stated...still, the check-- is odd since you later check++ having seemingly done nothing in between.

Comment: Where is the code you have written?  No code, no help!!! sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is too complicated, this simple logic should do it

1. Count the first value
2. Start a loop from the second value to the last
3. Subtract the current value from the previous, if the result is 0 then it's the same value, do not add to the counter otherwise add to the counter.

I wrote a program to show you how

**numbers.txt**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 5
14 62 48 14
1 3 5 7 9
123 456 789 1234 5678
34 34 34 34 34
1
1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 7 7 7 1 1
```

**program.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *file;
    char line[100];

    file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
    {
        char *start;
        int array[100];
        int count;
        int value;
        int step;

        count = 0;
        start = line;
        while (sscanf(start, "%d%n", array + count, &step) == 1)
        {
            start += step;
            count += 1;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "%d ", array[0]);
        value = 1;
        for (int i = 1 ; i < count ; ++i)
        {
            value += (array[i] - array[i - 1]) ? 1 : 0;
            fprintf(stderr, "%d ", array[i]);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, " -- %d\n", value);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to count unique numbers. They are trying to count the number of runs.

Comment: @JohnColeman That is correct. I do not want to calculate the total number of unique integers. I am trying to calculate what I edited above to explain more in detail. Please see my edit, sir. Thank you.

Comment: @Justin_Finland I just fixed it and it does what you want. Just don't sort the array, the rest is the same idea.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to check the current value to previous value of the array and check if they are equal or not something like this ::

```
int ans = 1;
for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) { //n is the number of elements in array
    if (a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
        ans++;
    }
}
printf("%d", ans);
```

I do not exactly understand why you use so many `check` in your code. What I do in this code is that I check my current element in the array (starting from `1`) and compare it with previous element, so if they are not equal you have a unique element in your array (sequentially), and hence I increment the `ans` which is the number of unique elements sequentially.

Here I start with `ans = 1` because I assume that there will be at least 1 element in your array and that will be unique in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are using that much code for.
But for what i understand you want to do, it a simple loop like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
    int count = 1;
    int i = 0;

    for(i=1; i<(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++) { //sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) calculates the length of the array
        if(array[i]!=array[i-1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```